# How to import and use "support" library in AIDE app?

Tags: android-fragments, android-support-library, aide

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now, but I have no idea how to achieve this. I'm trying to be able to use fragments in the app, but when I try to use the `import android.support*` library, I get an error.

A step by step explanation would be very beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the folder 'app' in your project, you have an option called 'Add to Project...'. Here you can choose what library to import. You propably want to use "com.android.support:support-v4:+".

BTW - in your java file, you should write `import android.support.v4.app.*`